# Ошибка при создании БД PostgreSql

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, jdbc, psql

Стоит postgresql 14 на Windows. Работало всё норм, не знаю что произошло. Но стал выдавать такую ошибку при создании БД.

`ВАЖНО: база данных "TestDb" не существует (pgjdbc: autodetected server-encoding to be windows-1251, if the message is not readable, please check database logs and/or host, port, dbname, user, password, pg_hba.conf) Подробности: Подкаталог базы данных "base/5802333" отсутствует.`

Но старые БД работают норм.

При попытках создать БД с помощью `psql` всё норм создаётся
`CREATE DATABASE TestDb WITH OWNER = postgres ENCODING = 'UTF8' CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;`

В списке тоже база присутствует, но при попытке переключиться на неё выдаёт

`подключиться к серверу "localhost" (::1), порту 5432 не удалось: ВАЖНО:  база данных "TestDb" не существует Сохранено предыдущее подключение`

Подскажите куда копать, в интернете, нечего похожего не нашёл. **Help!**

Comment: вероятно, сбой в файловой системе (стоит диски проверить) или кто-то руками поковырялся. В интернете похожего дофига, но прогноз неутешительный.  Если есть ценные базы, попытайся сделать дамп, а если нет - просто всё переустанови.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov В интернете, что-то не нашёл дофига инфы, если есть ссылки можете поделиться? Да прогноз не айс (. Сейчас как раз баз дампы делаю, потом буду переустанавливать, если не чего не найду.